# Creating new pages in Visual Studio using C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to write a Windows Forms application using C#, however I have never done this before. I have successfully created a login page which takes the user to a home page where 4 buttons are displayed. I am trying to find code to put inside each button that will take the user to a different page.

Answer (score 0):

In windows forms application, you have to call Show method on the Form which you want to show.

Let's say on Button1 click you want to show Form2, then below code will bring Form 2 up on the screen.

```
 private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Form2 obj = new Form2();
    if (obj == null)
    {
        obj.Parent = this;
    }
        obj.Show();
        this.Hide();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does this mean that when I press the button I will show a new form?

Comment: I would be careful here with `Form2 obj = new Form2();`. This can potentially lead up to infinite recursion. Personally, I would make the forms child of the first one.

Comment: @krobelusmeetsyndra - I agree.  Actually the application should be designed in such a way that there is always one parent window.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create, initialize and show the other forms.

```
frmSecond frm = new frmSecond();//You should call any other constructor, may be with some parameters
frm.Text ="I wanted to change the title";//Optional: You can change any property value if you need
frm.Show();
```

If you want to show the form, collect some information from user and return some values then you can use ShowDialog method instead of Show method

```
if(frm.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK){
    var myVar = frm.ReturnObject;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below approach for one parent window and new child window.
When you press the button new form opens:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
       {
          frm2.ShowDialog();
       }
}
```